# Search in JSON by id and name

Tags: mysql, query, select, mysql-5.7, json

I have this table:

```
id number
name text
```

row for example:

```
id name
1 {"vals":[{"id":123,"name":""}],"additional":"text"}
2 {"vals":[{"id":123}],"additional":"text text"}
3 {"vals":[{"id":222},{"id":123,"name":"this is the one"}],"additional":"text text"}
4 {"vals":[{"id":222,"name":"this is the one"},{"id":123}],"additional":"text text"}
```

I want to return the ids where vals[*].id=123 and their other `name` element is not empty(not other `name` in the json).
So only this one will turn:

```
    3 {"vals":[{"id":222},{"id":123,"name":"this is the one"}],"additional":"text text"}
```

I'm not strong with json type queries so I only got:

```
select id 
from tab
where name ->>"$.vals[0].id"=123
```

I should have done `"$.vals[*].id"`, but that returns to me `[123]` and that is not `= 123`

Appreciate your help!

Comment: If you're interested in using JSON, wouldn't you be better of with a more recent version of MySQL or MariaDB?  Not to mention PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'm on Aurora which doesn't have 8.0 version just yet :(

Answer (score 0):

JSON is always tricky and you have to search a lot of tutorials to get the hang of it.

But you can use normalized table instead of JSON.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` JSON
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tab
>   (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '{"vals":[{"id":123,"name":""}],"additional":"text"}'),
>   ('2', '{"vals":[{"id":123}],"additional":"text"}'),
>   ('3', '{"vals":[{"id":123,"name":"this"}],"additional":"text"}'),
>   ('4', '{"vals":[{"id":222,"name":"this"}],"additional":"text"}');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, name
> FROM tab WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(name->>'$.vals[*].id','123','$') 
> AND (name->>'$.vals[*].name' IS NOT NULL AND  NOT `name`->'$.vals[*].name' = JSON_ARRAY("")  )
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name                                                         
> -: | :------------------------------------------------------------
>  3 | {"vals": [{"id": 123, "name": "this"}], "additional": "text"}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9841a7ff8970d72cfeffcb4f1bbfb2ea)*

Comment: This is awesome! But your `4` value is different from mine and putting it in the fiddle actually returns it (which is "wrong") - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=83486625a02946151131599c26e4e2e4

Comment: The fiddle is using v8. :-(

Comment: if you change tio mysqlk 5.7 it works too, only older Version don't have json

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you change forth row with `('4', '{"vals":[{"id":222,"name":"this is the one"},{"id":123}],"additional":"text text"}');` - you will get extra row back

Comment: the result of `name`->'$.vals[*].name' is an Arrays with both Values, Json ios a string,with not that many possibilitys only if you make it with JSON_TABLE you can select probably the unly values fro mtghe array. but that is more that i wcan do. If you want more doe it yourself,

Comment: JSON_TABLE doesn't exists in 5.7 :( I guess I will go old school `name like '%"id": 123, "name": "_%"%'`

Comment: i know, that is why it is more than excessive to extract that information., you should try to use anther language like php or python c# c++ .... that can do much more with json, at least you have already eliminated some rows

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL 8.0.34 and data from the question post (note the JSON data is of type JSON instead of TEXT, and the column name is changed to `data` from `name`):

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  id INT,
  data JSON);

INSERT INTO tab VALUES
(1, '{ "vals": [ { "id": 123, "name": "" } ],"additional": "text 1" }'),
(2, '{ "vals": [ { "id": 123 } ], "additional": "text text 2" }'),
(3, '{ "vals": [ { "id": 222 }, { "id": 123, "name": "** this is the one **" } ], "additional": "text text 3" }'),
(4, '{ "vals": [ { "id": 222, "name": "this is the one" }, { "id": 123 } ], "additional": "text text 4" }');
```

The following query returns the expected result:

```
SELECT tab.id, ANY_VALUE(tab.data) AS data
FROM 
  tab, 
  JSON_TABLE(data->"$.vals", '$[*]' COLUMNS(id INT PATH '$.id', name CHAR(30) PATH '$.name')) AS jtab 
WHERE 
  jtab.id = 123 AND
  LENGTH(jtab.name) > 0
GROUP BY tab.id;

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id   | data
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3 | {"vals": [{"id": 222}, {"id": 123, "name": "** this is the one **"}], "additional": "text text 3"} 
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```